# Understanding statistical hypothesis tests in paper

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I'm a stats noob, so I don't really understand the statistic tests that the authors Ross, Greene, and House use to justify their results in their paper ["The 'false consensus effect'"](http://web.mit.edu/curhan/www/docs/Articles/biases/13_J_Experimental_Social_Psychology_279_%28Ross%29.pdf).

For example, in their first study they are looking at how personal agreement affects how much a participant thinks other people would agree or disagree. It gives the counts for agreement and disagreement for four scenarios, the average estimated percentage of peers that participants would say that would agree or disagree, and a mysterious "F" value (page 283). Additionally, when discussing the results they say the following (page 284):

> When each story was treated as a “fixed” variable in an analysis of variance combining the data for all four stories, the main effect of Rater’s Choice
>   was highly significant, F(1, 312) = 49.1, p < .001, while the Story x Rater’s
>   Choice interaction was trivial, F(1, 312) = 1.37, p > .10.

This is probably a very basic statistics question, but I have no context for what this "F" function is, and where they are getting the numbers they are feeding into it. Thank you!

Comment: A very useful question. Freequently techniques are misunderstood or misused  to prove anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper includes the phrase "F-ratio". This is almost certainly the [F-statistic](http://www.statisticshowto.com/f-statistic/) produced during analysis of variance [(ANOVA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance). The [F-ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance#The_F-test) takes the ratio $F = \frac{\text{variance between treatments}}{\text{variance within treatments}}$ and uses a lookup table (i.e., a conversion between the F-statistic and a probability) to find the probability that the explanatory value of the treatments could occur by chance alone. In the paper, the notation $F(.,.)\rightarrow F(df,n)$ is implied on page 285 by comparing the text with the footnote on that page.

Comment: +1 To clarify (in response to OP's question), the "F()" you see is not a function at all but just the standard format for reporting statistical tests. The numbers in the parentheses are the [degrees of freedom](http://www.rondotsch.nl/degrees-of-freedom/), and they correspond to how many groups are being compared (df1 = # of groups - 1) and how many subjects were tested (df2 = N - # of groups). The value reported after the = is the F ratio itself, and the p value tells you the probability of observing that ratio or larger if the null hypothesis were true.

Comment: Thanks @Carl and @RoseHatman. I had considered that it may have been d.o.f. in the F() notation but the numbers didn't make sense. It requires a little bit more context than what was in my snippet, but there were 320 participants. If `df1 = groups - 1`, and `df2 = N - groups`, and N = 320, how can the number of groups be 2 for df1 (where df1 = 1), and 8 for df2 (where df2 = 312)? Unless `N` is not really 320 and they discounted results without disclosure.